# Returning pointer to inherited class C++

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a base-class (`node`) which gets inherited by `node2D`, which gets inherited by `CSprite2D` (I am working on a game-engine)

I have a vector of pointers to my objects inherited from NODE.

In my function `CNode* getNodeByName(QString name)` I return a CNode, but I can't do

```
CSprite2D* sprite = getNodeByName("hello")
```

Why is that and what could be a workaround? I already tried it returning a CSprite2D and it worked like a charm.
I already tried to declare my function as `virtual CNode* getNodeByName(Qstring name)`

PS: I am using Qt if that matters. And also, I'm new to C++ so I it possible I oversaw something.

Comment: you can cast your CNode* to CSprite2D* if you are sure it is of type CSpirite2D* see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/ for more information about casting and different types of cast.

Comment: What's the relationship between `CNode` and `CSprite2D`?

Comment: CSprite2D inherits by CNode2D and CNode2D inherits from CNode. @Peter

Comment: @basslo could you pleasy give my a little example? I can't seem to find a way to implement a typecasting function.

Comment: Ok, Yes, I am totally sure it's a CSprite2D so... Thank you very much ;)

Comment: If you could please but this into a real answer so the next people can easyli find the fix it would be great @basslo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if CSprite2D inherits CNode (in you question you said node) you can do the following :

```
CSprite2D* sprite = static_cast< CSprite2D* >(getNodeByName("hello"));
```

only if you are sure that the object returned is a CSprite2D*, otherwise it is **undefined behavior**.

You can also use dynamic_cast (see example in the [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/typecasting/)), dynamic_cast wwill return a null pointer or  if the cast fails.

```
CSprite2D* sprite = dynamic_cast< CSprite2D* >(getNodeByName("hello"));
```